# Why am I unable to switch my Ruby version using RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I ran:

`rvm install 2.1.0`

Followed by:

`rvm use 2.1.0`

However, my Ruby version given by `ruby -v` yields `2.0.0` which is my system build.

Why is RVM not behaving as expected?

Comment: Can you check if the RVM folder is on your path (echo $PATH in the terminal) and before `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/bin`, `/usr/sbin` or `/sbin`?

Comment: What error messages are you getting from the `rvm install 2.1.0` command?

Comment: @JimmyThompson which RVM folder? `$HOME/.rvm/bin`?

Comment: @ingo No error messages from the install!

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking rvm and ruby? rvm is largely implemented as bash functions, so you need to execute all the commands in the same shell. Invoking rvm in a subshell or another process will discard all the environment variables and shell state that rvm sets up.

```
(rvm use 2.1.0) #subshell
ruby -v # still 2.0.0
./change_rvm_version.sh # execute shell script that calls rvm
ruby -v # still 2.0.0
rvm use 2.1.0
ruby -v # should be 2.1.0
```

Comment: All the commands are run in the same shell, running the commands just as you did did not yield the output you received.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

at the bottom of your `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile`) file

and invoke it with `. .bashrc` ( or just do a new shell)

Answer (score 0):

`rvm use 2.1.0`

Will only change you're ruby version **locally**, it's used when you're testing multiple versions of ruby. If you want to change you're default ruby version **globally** using rvm you need to use the `default` command.

Like this:

`rvm --default use 2.1.0`

Comment: I did this as well - it didn't change my Ruby version!